# Use of Chinese Remainder Theorem in proof of RSA correctness

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

RSA

- $\gcd(p,q) = 1$
- $N = pq$
- $ed = 1 \bmod{\phi(N)}$

The proof of correctness of RSA involves 2 cases

Case 1)  $\gcd(m, N) = 1$

I understand the proof of correctness for this case using Euler's Theorem

Case 2) $\gcd(m, N) \neq 1$

For proving this, the Chinese Remainder Theorem is used

All the proofs say that as per CRT

If

- $x = y \pmod{p}$   - 1
  and
- $x = y \pmod{q}$   - 2

then

- $x = y \pmod{pq}$  ====> 3

I know that Line 1 is true & it's easily proven, but how does Chinese Remainder theorem come in here? How do you use CRT to get from (1)&(2) to (3)?

For e.g. check the Wikipedia article (it's not just Wikipedia, I saw it in several other places also)

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Proof_using_Fermat's_little_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Proof_using_Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

In that article check the line "To check whether two numbers, such as med and m, are congruent mod pq, it suffices (and in fact is equivalent) to check that they are congruent mod p and mod q separately" - they have [note2] for it where it says "This is part of the Chinese remainder theorem, although it is not the significant part of that theorem."

Comment: This post is too long, I think -- I can't see exactly where your problem lies. Is it going from $x\equiv y\bmod p$ and $x\equiv y\bmod q$ to $x\equiv y\bmod pq$? Or is it going from $x= yb_1q+yb_2p$ to $x\equiv y\bmod p$ and $x\equiv y\bmod q$?

Comment: @TonyK - The first one! From $x\equiv y\bmod q$ and  $x\equiv y\bmod q$ to $x\equiv y\bmod pq$

Comment: @TonyK - However, I have reached up to $x = y b_1 q + y b_2 p$. If from there, I can go to $x \equiv y \bmod pq$, that would also be the same

Comment: If $x\equiv y\bmod p$ and $x\equiv y\bmod q$ then by definition $x-y$ is divisible by $p$ and also by $q$, and hence also by $lcm(p,q)=pq$. Therefore $x\equiv y\bmod pq$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - I understood your answer - I deleted my earlier question to you. However, this doesn't seem to use Chinese Remainder theorem at all. I see that if $x \equiv y \bmod p$ and $x \equiv y \bmod q$, then by CRT, $x \equiv y \bmod pq$ - so why is CRT needed at all here.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct prime numbers, and let $a$ be an integer that is divisible by both $p$ and $q$. Then $a$ is divisible by $pq$. (Do you agree?)

In other words, if $a\equiv 0 \bmod p$ and $a\equiv 0\bmod q$, then $a\equiv 0\bmod pq$.

Now just let $a=x-y$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood this. Just one question - this doesn't seem to need the Chinese Remainer Theorem at all. But at many places, I see that if $x \equiv y \bmod p$ and $x \equiv y \bmod q$, then by CRT, $x \equiv y \bmod pq$ - so why is CRT needed at all here.

Comment: The CRT is not needed in this part. It _is_ needed to find $b_1$ and $b_2$.

Comment: No, they are using CRT of this - For e.g. check the Wikipedia article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Proof_using_Fermat's_little_theorem

Comment: In that article check the line "To check whether two numbers, such as med and m, are congruent mod pq, it suffices (and in fact is equivalent) to check that they are congruent mod p and mod q separately" - they have [note2] for it where it says "This is part of the Chinese remainder theorem, although it is not the significant part of that theorem." And it's not just this wiki article - several places say this follows from CRT

Comment: They are referring to [the uniqueness part of the CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Uniqueness). What TonyK did here is to give a proof of this.